# Image charges for conducting planes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

> [image]

Hello, we had 2 ideas for the layout: we couldn't decide between a star and a diamond.  How would you set up the image charges.  Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this a question to discuss with your instructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General approach is: remove conducting surface and guess charges values and positions such that the potential of all the points where the conducting surface was would be the same. If you managed to do it you can bring back the conducting surface and it would affect nothing: no charges would appear on the surface because the potentials of all the points is the same.

Now remove all the charges "outside" the surface. Some charges would appear on it, but the configuration of electric field "inside" the surface would not change.

The trick is to guess the positions of charges and prove that all the required points have same potential. Try diamond position of charges and try to calculate potentials in the points where conducting surface is located. I bet potentials would be different.

But if you take 6 charges $q$, $-q$, $q$, etc., the potentials of all the points on surface would be $0$ because of the symmetry. This guess is correct.